Inserting multiple items of data into tables and a unique ID into a table along with a query
I'm trying to capture data from a query and save it all into Table1. I created another table2, too, for a one-to-many relationship.
The setup is this - Table1:



Capture_Num
Capture_ID
F3
F4
F5



Table2 contains just these columns:



Capture_ID
Cap_Date



So the Capture_ID in table2 will be inserted into the Table1's Capture_ID column, and the rest of the SELECT query. I can't think of any solution.
Is there a way also to INSERT data into table2 and at the same time INSERT the unique Capture_ID to table1 along with the SELECT query that I wrote?
So if I have a query that returns this



F3
F4
F5




John
100
1/1/2024


Peter
200
2/2/2024


Luke
300
3/3/2024



When I execute the SQL statement, I want it to be like
Table1



Capture_Num
Capture_ID
F3
F4
F5




1
1
John
100
1/1/2024


2
1
Peter
200
2/2/2024


3
1
Luke
300
3/3/2024



on Table2, I'd like to add a data too.



Capture_ID(Unique)
Cap_Date




1
12/19/2024



I hope you can help me out.

I understand it so that you have a table 2 containing one row per day, with an integer as capture_id and a date as cap_date, which I would call calendar, and you would want to add the capture id to table 1, with the current date's capture_id as from table 2.
In that case, I would actually create table 2 so that the capture_id is not a sequence, but the result of:
YEAR(cap_date)*10000+MONTH(cap_date)*100+DAY(cap_date)
... giving you this table:



capture_id
cap_date




20241218
2024-12-18


20241219
2024-12-19



And so, you could insert into table 1 just using the same expression as for table 2 for cap_date:
YEAR(DATE())*10000+MONTH(DATE())*100+DAY(DATE())
As for capture_num, which is the ordinal capture number within a capture date, I need to look up if MS Access now supports window functions like ROW_NUMBER(), and I'll come back here if I find out.
Update: MS Access still does not support window functions. Other than a Visual Basic procedure, you won't be able to work on sequence numbers within a date.

Here is how: RowNumber. See my repository at GitHub: VBA.RowNumbers.
